# Updating Wordpress tracked with Subversion

Tags: wordpress, svn, versions

I have all my client sites on their own repos for tracking changes with svn but when I update through the Wordpress admin panel (Wordpress or plugins) the directories for them are deleted and replaced, removing the .svn files.

This then breaks my svn as I keep getting the following,

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Directory '/website/trunk/wp-content/plugins/plugin-dir/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

Does anyone know a way to auto-update through the Wordpress CMS with it deleting any svn files?

Comment: I think this page has the answer for you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/updating-a-wordpress-plugins-breaks-svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has a procedure of setting up the process properly:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/updating-a-wordpress-plugins-breaks-svn